# If statement evaluating true no matter what. Python 3.3.0

Tags: python-3.x

```
title=("The Game")
print (title)
start = input("Begin?")
if start == "no" or "n":
    print ("Too Bad")
    import antigravity;
if start == "yes" or "y":
    print ("Welcome to the Experiment")
else:
    print ("IDK");
```

No matter what my response is, the first "if" will always be resolved as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement isn't doing what you think it is. Python is evaluating the first comparison, `start == "no"` then comparing that to to `"n"`, which being a non-empty string, is always true. Essentially it was `(start == "no") or "n"`.

This is what you probably meant:

```
if start == "no" or start == "n":
```

but that's not really the python way. This is what you're looking for:

```
if start in ["no", "n"]:
```

That checks to see if the string value of `start` is in the list of acceptable string values. You'll probably also want to compare lowercase values only with something like `start.lower()`